# How can I remove the white rectangle created when opening a file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

How can I remove the white rectangle created when opening a file? When I open an image in Illustrator, I see a small rectangle in the center of the image and when I save the image using "Save For Web", Illustrator saves only the part within the rectangle but I want save all of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [Artboard](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/artboard-overview.html) and you don't remove it. You can make it larger or smaller by going to `File > Document Setup` and then click on `Edit Artboards`:

[image: Document Setup Panel]

Your artwork must be contained in the Artboard. I'd suggest you read the link above from Adobe to get a better understanding of this concept.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little on what Ryan said, there is a faster way to edit your Artboards.  Simply click on the `Artboard Tool` and resize them to fit.

[image: artboard-tool]

**The even *faster* way is to automatically size your Artboard to fit your artwork.**

I have this image of a tree that extends beyond my Artboard

[image: tree-ext]

Go to `Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds`

[image: menu]

And there you have it:

[image: final]